# Не работает щелчек по области закрытия окна

Tags: jquery

скажите в чем проблема, не работает в safari щелчек на пустую область и закрытия окна. В google chrome все ок

```js
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var animate = getParameterByName('animate', document.referrer);

            if (animate === 'false') {
                document.querySelector('.widget')
                    .classList.add('show');
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.widget')
                    .classList.add('open');
            }
            $('.currency-question').click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
         $('.currency-text').removeClass('active');  
  });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Логика в

```
$('.currency-question').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

и в

```
$(document).click(function(e) {   
  // check that the click is not in '.currency-question'
  $('.currency-question').next().removeClass('active');  
});
```

должна быть симметричной.

Comment: А как исправить подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Never3D Я привел исправленный код - не такой, как у Вас.

Comment: Также не работает в safari((

Comment: исправленный тоже не работает(